# Import Public key of JKS to Pem and vice-versa

Tags: java, openssl, jks

I have a `Java Server` Which understands `.jks format` and client which understand `.pem` .  I have generate `Server key-pair` using `keytool` and `Client key-pair` using `openssl` but for mutual authentication how do I import `client's public key into server's JKS` and `Server Public key into client .pem` file.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent versions of keytool understand PEM. So in those cases one uses

```
keytool -importcert ...
```

and assuming that you've already imported the cert you've signed the client cert with (as a trustcacert) you should be good. Otherwise also import that with the -trustcacert (or if it is iselfsigned - add that flag to the import).

If you are on an older java, say on RHEL, then you need to convert it to DER format first. Conversion is done with:

```
openssl x509 -in client.pem -out client.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in client.pem -out client.net -outform NET
```

And that should be it. On the client side - one generally does not import the server cert into the client cert - but imports these separately into your application. So to answer that one would need to know what your client application is.

Comment: Could you please explain more in deatail.

Comment: Sorry - you'll have to be a lot more exact in order to allow one to add detail beyond above.

What versions/SKD, what is the client app/framework, what is the server app/framework, are you using self signed or is there a CA involved. Perhaps start with a description of the client and the server and the commands you used to create your keys.